# If $n\equiv 1\ [5]$ then $Q\mid P_n$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, arithmetic, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

> We consider the two polynomials with real coefficients:
>   $${\displaystyle P_{n}(X)=X^{4n}+X^{3n}+X^{2n}+X^{n}+1 \quad \mbox{ with } n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}}$$ and $${\displaystyle Q(x)=X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1}$$
>   then:
>
> - Choose the correct option. more than one may be correct
> - $a)$ If $n$  is multiple of $5$ then $Q$ divides $P_n$
> - $b)$ If $n\equiv 1\ [5]$ then $Q$ divides $P_n$
> - $c)$ If $Q$ divides $P_n$ then $n$ is even
> - $d)$ None of the above statements is correct

**My proof:**

note that: $P_n(x)=Q(x^n)$

- **$c)$ is false** since $n=1$ (odd) and we've $Q=P_{1} \iff Q\mid P_{1}$ and $P_{1}\mid Q$
- **i think $b)$ is true** :

suppose that $n\equiv 1\ [5]$ then $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}\ \mbox{ s.t.}\quad n=5k+1$

$$P_n(X)=X^{4(5k+1)}+X^{3(5k+1)}+X^{2(5k+1)}+X^{5k+1}+1$$

and since $${\displaystyle Q(x)=X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1=\dfrac{X^{5}-1}{X-1}}$$
then we can factorized in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$:

note that :
$$\displaystyle \mathcal{U}_5\setminus\{1\}=\left\{ e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}},e^{\frac{4i\pi}{5}},e^{\frac{6i\pi}{5}},e^{\frac{8i\pi}{5}} \right\}$$

then:

$${\displaystyle Q(x)=(X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^{2})(X-\alpha^{3})(X-\alpha^{4})\quad \mbox{ with }\alpha=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}} } $$

> note that :
>
> if $P_n(\alpha)=P_n(\alpha^{2})=P_n(\alpha^{3})=P_n(\alpha^{4})=0$ then
>   $(X-\alpha)(X-\alpha^{2})(X-\alpha^{3})(X-\alpha^{4})\mid P_n$

Thus, it suffices to show that $$P_n(\alpha)=P_n(\alpha^{2})=P_n(\alpha^{3})=P_n(\alpha^{4})=0$$

- $P_n(\alpha)=e^{{\frac{8i\pi}{5}}(5k+1)}+e^{{\frac{6i\pi}{5}}(5k+1)}+e^{{\frac{4i\pi}{5}}(5k+1)}+e^{{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}(5k+1)}+1=Q(\alpha)=0 $

the same for others.

- **$a)$ false**
- **$d)$ false**
- Is my proof correct ?

Comment: yes, they do not even need to be in order; take $x^{1917} + x^{343} + x^{111} + x^{19} + 1$

Comment: Looks good to me. Your argument in proving (b) actually works to show that $Q\mid P_n$ if and only if $n$ is not a multiple of five.